# Can the gem prawn be used to create PDFs with embedded video?

Tags: ruby, flash, rubygems, prawn

Is is possible to use prawn http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/ to create a document with embedded flash?

I have gone over the api and am coming up empty.

If prawn doesn't yet have this feature, can any of the other pdf generators do it  (My guess is that all the ones that rely on webkit will be an automatic no)

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible, poured over the api's and to the best of my abilities I came up empty.  Answering my own questions to hopefully allow others to avoid doing all the research